# Conversion of Back EMF units from Vpeak/KRPM to V/Hz to find maximum speed of Motor

Tags: pmsm

I am trying to understand the different units of back EMF used for a PMSM Motor.
I have a Motor specification that tells me that the Back EMF constant 'Ke' is 4.64 Vpeak/KRPM.
[image: Motor Specification]
How do I go about converting this to Volts/Hz?

I need the back emf constant in Volts per Hz so that I will use that to calculate the maximum achievable electrical speed of the Motor.
[image: Maximum electrical speed]

Comment: PS: Is it as simple as saying 1RPM = 1 Hz, So Vpeak per 1 KRPM = Vpeak per 1 KHz?

Comment: 1000 rpm is 16.66667 Hz, so that is 278 mV  (peak voltage) per Hz.